# Find and replace for JSON with sed or awk

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed

So I need to be able to inject a value into JSON using sed or awk (preferably on one line) and I cannot install any external libraries to help me.

An example of the json is something like `{"version":"0.5363"}`

I'd need to be able to inject a new value for version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ echo '{"version":"0.5363"}' | sed 's/\({"version":"\)[^"]*\("}\)/\1newvalue\2/g'
{"version":"newvalue"}
```

In the above sed command, replace the `newvalue` with value you want. Add inline edit option `-i` to save the changes made.

```
sed -i 's/regex/replacement/g' file
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if version is next within JSON

Comment: Nevermind. It work's if I remove the brackets. Thanks very much!

Comment: for os x, you must specify a backup argument when editing a file, e.g.: `sed -i '.bak' 's/\({"version":"\)[^"]*\("}\)/\1newvalue\2/g' test`

reference: https://www.mkyong.com/mac/sed-command-hits-undefined-label-error-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

We can use `\s*` to match any whitespace between fields, which is irrelevant in JSON:

```bash
$ echo '{ "version": "0.5363" }' | sed 's/\s*\("version"\s*:[^"]*\)\s*\"[^"]*\"/\1\"newvalue\"/g'

{ "version": "newvalue" }
```